# Read and Write table to text file

Tags: android, file

I'm working on an Achievement system for Android and I'm just looking for a simple way to store all the achievements and your progress for each.
I need to store: id, title, description, points, current value, max value, and an image path for EACH achievement.

I tried using the SQLite services and everything but I can't seem to get that working that well, so I just want to use some basic text tables for now. I know you use the FileBuffer and I know how to write to text files, I'm just not sure the best approach to format them and how to read them in.

I was thinking of formatting the table something like this:

```
{
    {
        id = 0,
        Title = "Sample Achievement",
        Desc = "Sample description",
        Points = 5,
        CurVal = 3,
        MaxVal = 10,
        Img = "path/to/img.jpg",
     }
     {
        id = 1;
        ...
```

That would give me access to each achievement as its own subtable, or something like that and I can build an Achievement object around the values I get back for later use.

Answer (score 0):

you can start creating a database like below.

```
private static String db_path = "/data/data/com.yourproject/databases/mysqlitedb";
private SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = null;

public SQLiteDatabase getSQLiteDatabase() {
    try {

        sqliteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(db_path, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        sqliteDatabase.setVersion(1);
        sqliteDatabase.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        sqliteDatabase.setLockingEnabled(true);

        return sqliteDatabase;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return null;
    }

}
```

after that you can create your table like below.

```
public void createTable() {
    try {

        if (sqliteDatabase != null) {
            sqliteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                    + "Achievement" + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Title TEXT, Desc TEXT,"
                    + " Points NUMERIC," + " CurVal NUMERIC, MaxVal NUMERIC, "
                    + " Img TEXT);");


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    } 

}
```

you can insert data to your table like below.

```
public int insert(String table, Hashtable<String, String> FieldsAndValues) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int count=1;
    try {
        if (sqliteDatabase == null) {
            sqliteDatabase = getSQLiteDatabase();
        }

        Enumeration e = FieldsAndValues.elements();
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        for (e = FieldsAndValues.keys(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
            String key = (String) e.nextElement();
            String value = (String) FieldsAndValues.get(key);

            initialValues.put(key, value);

        }

        sqliteDatabase.insert(table, null, initialValues);

        return count;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Remember that, all these three method should be under one class.

if you able to manage up-to creating database and your table(by calling these methods in your initial activity) inserting data will be a piece of cake, will help you.